# Matlab -> Python. Reading heterogeneous 1D binary array from disk

Tags: python, matlab, binaryfiles, fread

Say we have a simple, small file with a 1D array holding different value types, with a specific structure (first item is MATLAB `uint`, second value is MATLAB `uint`, and the rest of values are `float`)

How can I  read such an array of **heterogeneous** types from a file in Python?

The equivalent code in MATLAB is below.

```
function M = load_float_matrix(fileName)

fid = fopen(fileName);
if fid < 0
    error(['Error during opening the file ' fileName]);
end

rows = fread(fid, 1, 'uint');
cols = fread(fid, 1, 'uint');
data = fread(fid, inf, 'float');

M = reshape(data, [cols rows])';

fclose(fid);

end
```

Note: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146031/what-is-the-equivalent-of-fread-from-matlab-in-python) describes the following approach to read three consecutive `uint32` values:

```
f = open(...)
import array
a = array.array("L")  # L is the typecode for uint32
a.fromfile(f, 3)
```

but, how do I know that L is the typecode for `uint32`? What about the other types?  (e.g. `float`).

Also, how can I read consecutive values from `f`? Would `a.fromfile` move the read pointer in the file forward?

Comment: Unless you've a reason to avoid having numpy as a dependency, google numpy.loadtxt

Answer (score 3):

Try numpy.

Below is one way of doing it.

```
import numpy as np
f = open(filename,"r")
N = np.fromfile(fp,dtype=np.int32,count=2)
a = np.fromfile(fp,dtype=np.float64)
a = np.resize(a,N)
```

with this you can also read a mixed format/type( text + binary ) file. It is possible to combine line 3 and line 4 by properly formatting the dtype option, google for more examples.